# No Feed on Android app after login

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

As soon as I login using my Stack Exchange ID on the Android app, the feed fails to load.

If I use the app without logging in everything's fine. If I login using Google or Facebook, I see the feed.

I have tried reinstalling the app but the problem persists.

Comment: The account you posted this question using does not have a Facebook or Google login associated with it. What account are you logging into using those?

Comment: A Stack Exchange id.

Comment: I do have the same issue.  Stack exchange android apps. when not logged in using stack exchange id feeds are working but as soon as I logged in feeds are not showing anymore

Comment: Got fixed on its own.I guess the folks here fixed the bug.